# create hyperlink that open in new tab/window using external javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create a link that opens in a new window/tab to my HTML menu item (Try, Trying, TryTry) using external javascript? (and not edit anything from the HTML file)

Html file:

```
<div id="highlights" class="container">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="Try">Try!</li>
            <li id="Trying">Trying!</li>
            <li id="TryTry">TryTry!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want each of (Try, Trying, TryTry) to be their own ling that opens a new tab/window?

Comment: @Jacob yes!! ..

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path you want each link to go to as the href.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/spliffmon/3anzm18t/10/) is a link to it in JSFiddle as StackOverflow snippets do not allow popups / new tabs to be opened.

```html
<div id="highlights" class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="Try"><a href="link/to/try" target="_blank">Try!</a>!</li>
      <li id="Trying"><a href="link/to/trying" target="_blank">Trying!</a>!</li>
      <li id="TryTry"><a href="link/to/trytry" target="_blank">TryTry!</a>!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I didn't mention it previously. But I am not allowed to edit anything to my HTML file

Comment: Oh. Is the above still the desired end goal? Just modify is via js?

Comment: Something like that but I'll need to create that function in js file instead but I'm not sure how

Answer (score 0):

Use the `target="_blank"` to opens the linked document in a new window or tab.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("Try").innerHTML = `<li id="Try"><a href="link/to/try" target="_blank">Try!</a></li>`

document.getElementById("Trying").innerHTML = `<li id="Trying"><a href="link/to/trying" target="_blank">Trying!</a></li>`

document.getElementById("TryTry").innerHTML = `<li id="TryTry"><a href="link/to/trytry" target="_blank">TryTry!</a></li>`
```

```html
<div id="highlights" class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li id="Try">Try!</li>
      <li id="Trying">Trying!</li>
      <li id="TryTry">TryTry!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once again. As StackOverflow doesn't allow snippets to open new pages [here](https://jsfiddle.net/spliffmon/3anzm18t/37/) is a link to JSFiddle

Comment: because it's a brand new javascript file, do I need to add anything else? eg. functions().